# QGIS clip overlapping polygons based on condition

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I have a shapefile with polygons representing a collection of nautical charts.  The charts have different scales (an attribute in the layer) and some overlap.  I want to create a layer which eliminates overlaps choosing the chart that has the best (lowest) scale.  The way I see this working is that for each polygon, I need to see if there are any areas that overlap with a polygon with a lower scale value and remove that area for the polygon.

The end result is that I have a layer where anywhere I query, I will have only one polygon and it will represent the chart with the lowest scale for the point queried.

For example with this input (assuming red scale > yellow scale > green scale):

[image]

I would want the green polygon to remain as it was originally.
The yellow polygon would become:
[image]

And the red polygon would become:

[image]

Comment: Union them, then encode the outcome and  dissolve.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by encode the outcome.  Sorry, I am quite new to GIS.  I can union the layer to itself and then end up with polygons which show the overlaps and provide me with the attributes of each pair of overlapping polygons.  If I dissolve that directly I just get one big polygon

Comment: Exactly, which is why you need to do a little logic to indicate your encoding rules (if green, and anything else, then green; if yellow, but not green, then yellow; otherwise red), *then* dissolve.

Answer (score 0):

My layer have an integer field with scales.

1. Union, with the chart layer as Input Layer, no overlay layer. Output will have duplicate geometries where polygons overlap.
2. Aggregate to keep only the minimum scale:
   [image]
3. Dissolve by chart field, with Advanced parameter `Keep disjoint features separate=Yes`

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is definitely helping me out.  I think I have almost got this to work I can get it to a "flat" set of polygons but the only attribute I have is the scale.  Is there any way to retain the other attributes of the polygon that ends up "winning"

Comment: You can add all fields to aggregate. Easiest by executing Union then **Load fields from template layer** using Union output. Then set aggregate function = First value for all fields except scale